# rpm yum install : how to put conflicts on an already installed package?

Tags: upgrade, rpm, yum, rhel, rpm-spec

I'm trying to stop installation of an rpm if I have a particular version of a package already installed.

Say I have 2 packages **A-7.1.1.rpm & Main_package-1.0.rpm** to be installed.

And I've A-1.4.0.rpm already installed on the machine. So what I want to achieve is that, if the installed version of A < 7.1.0 then upgrade of Main_package should not happen.

I tried to put Conflicts tag in the spec file of Main_package as follows.
**Conflicts : A < 7.1.0**
And executed `yum install *.rpm`

Here yum finds a latest version of package 'A' in the directory (ie, A-7.1.1.rpm), it doesn't conflict. What I want to check is, if the machine has a particular version of package A.

I could not find any other tags that I can use within the spec file.
Is there any way I can achieve this?

Note: I can't have this check inside a script which then invokes `yum install *.rpm`

I can execute only `yum install *.rpm`, nothing else.

Comment: Conflicts is the correct tag. When you invoke `yum install`; you say it doesn't conflict. Yum should allow installation of A-7.1.1, but not together with your main_package. Does yum allow installation of both together? You could check as well if the main_package has the correct conflicts tag set; using `rpm -qp /path/to/Main_package-1.0.rpm --conflicts`

Comment: PS: don't ask questions on Two sites together! please remove your question on unix/linux!

Comment: Hi Chris, yes. rpm -qp shows the correct conflict.  If I install both together - installation is going through, because yum sees that I've a version > than what I've mentioned in the conflict tag. But If I try to install main_package alone, conflict is working.  What I want to compare is against the already installed package A-1.4.0  Yes. i'll remove the question from other site.

Comment: yum is working correctly; you're just not clear when asking him what to do... you ask him to install main_package, which conflicts with A < 7.1.0; on the other hand you give him a solution to the problem: upgrade A so he can work with 7.1.1. So in fact the real problem is that he allows an upgrade of A? You are not telling him he can't...

Comment: hmm. yeah yum is working as expected.  Is there a way to stop installation if yum finds an already installed package of a particular version when I do yum install *.rpm

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution, but it is not very clean and not recommended: you can check in the pre-section of your package **A** whether the other version is installed and abort installation:

```
%pre
if [[ $(rpm -q A --qf "%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}") == "1.4.0" ]]
then
    # abort installation in this case!
    exit 1
fi
```

see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472880/how-to-abort-the-installation-of-an-rpm-package-if-some-conditions-are-not-met-i) for some more information.

I do think you should rethink your design, because it is a quite ugly solution (and note that A-7.1.1 won't have this %pre section and will thus still install without problem)

Comment: You can also write to `stderr` for the user to see _why_ the install aborted as well as the recommended resolution

Comment: I haven't tried %pre yet.  I've 4-5 rpms in my directory. When I run yum install *.rpm, It'd be a single transaction. After the first rpm fails in its %pre section, yum will try to install the remaining rpms as it's a single transaction. This is my understanding. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: One more thing that I'm trying to do is to touch a dummy file as part of previous install, and during upgrade I'll just check for the presence of that file using 'requires' tag.  But 'requires : filelocation' has not helped me though.

Comment: you are wrong :) yum will indeed make one big transaction; and if A-7.1.1 cannot install, then Main_package won't install either; due to its missing dependency

Comment: Requires doensn't work on files that aren't installed by a rpm package

Answer (score 0):

yum has means to configure "don't upgrade package XXX" by pattern through CLI option or configuration. See https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10185